# VF - apex:inputField does not show the lookup icon with master-detail relationship

Tags: visualforce, inputfield

When I add an apex:inputField for a master-detail relationship it does not allow you to choose a parent via the lookup icon - it only shows the name of a parent if I append a record ID in the URL. If no record ID is specified, it only shows the name of the field, but no lookup icon.

[image]

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Scholarship_Award__c">
    <h1>2020-2021 Academic Year</h1>
    <apex:form >
    <!-- Hi -->
    <apex:pageBlock title="Add Scholarship Awards">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Scholarship_Award__c.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Scholarship_Award__c.Year__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Scholarship_Award__c.Recipient__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think you would need to use a custom controller to support entering detail records to a variable parent

Comment: Thank you. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pass in an ID for the parent?  Detail records for M-D relationships can't be created in the standard SFDC UI without starting with a parent

Comment: Yes. I am developing a custom VF page for our external partners who are non-SF users. They will be inputting data of which we don't have so they will choose from the lookup which parent they would like to associate their new record with.

Comment: I don't have time to try/prove this but a) write a controllerExtension whose constructor creates a in-memory placeholder parent object using an Id of `keyPrefix000000000000000`and a detail record (in memory) that points at the in-memory parent. b) then implement a controller extension `save()` that verifies that a real parent was chosen.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any good resources on learning/developing custom extension controllers for creating in-memory placeholders? Am new to VF

Answer (score 0):

You need to use actual lookup field value="{!Scholarship_Award__c}" instead of value="{!Scholarship_Award__c.Name}"